# An inequality regarding the derivative of two concave functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ be two strictly increasing, strictly concave and twice differentiable functions with $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=g'(0)>0$. We have $f(x)\leq g(x)$. Is it true that $f'(x)\leq g'(x)$ for any $x$ in the domain?

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $f(x)=x$ for $0\le x<1$ and $f(x)=1+x/4$ for $x>1$ (we can modify near $x=1$ to make it smooth). Then $g$ could be a similar piecewise linear function that starts out with a large slope on $[0,1/2]$ and has slope $1/2$, say, on $(1/2,\infty)$.

I didn't satisfy your assumption that $f'(0)=g'(0)$, but we can easily bypass this by letting $f,g$ start out as the same function, and then we switch to my example.