# A bound on the derivative of a concave function via another concave function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ be two strictly concave, strictly increasing, twice differentiable functions, such that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\to\infty$, i.e. there exists $M>0$ and $x_0$ such that 
$$f(x)\leq Mg(x)\qquad \forall x\geq x_0.$$
Is it true that $f'(x)=O(g'(x))$ as $x\to\infty$?

(this is an extensions of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692345/an-inequality-regarding-the-derivative-of-two-concave-functions))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  We first construct a function $h:[-1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as follows: For integers $n \in \{-1, 0, 1, 2, ...\}$ we want $h$ to be: 
$$ h(n) = \frac{1}{(n+2)!} \quad \forall n \in \{-1, 0, 1, 2, ...\} $$
These values are positive and strictly decreasing.  So, we can interpolate them to get the full function $h(x)$ that is differentiable, positive, and satisfies $h'(x)<0$ for all $x \geq -1$.

Define $g:[-1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = \int_{-1}^{x} h(t)dt$.  Then $g'(x)=h(x)>0$ and $g''(x)=h'(x)<0$ for all $x\geq -1$. So $g$ is increasing, twice differentiable, and strictly concave.

Now define $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = g(x-1)$.  Then 
$$ f(x) = g(x-1) \leq g(x) \quad \forall x \in [0,\infty)$$
Furthermore, for integers $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ we get: 
$$ \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)} = \frac{g'(n-1)}{g'(n)} = \frac{1/(n+1)!}{1/(n+2)!}\rightarrow \infty $$
and so the conjecture $f'(x) = O(g'(x))$ fails.

Comment: Thanks Michael!
I wonder if one can find a similar counter example when $g(x)=\log x$?

Comment: I don't know. The case $g(x)=\log(x)$ seems more difficult. However, if you assume $f(x)\rightarrow\infty, g(x)\rightarrow\infty$, and that limits of $f(x)/g(x)$ and $f’(x)/g’(x)$ exist, then L’Hopital’s rule ensures they are the same (regardless of concavity).